# React JS setState not updating value

Tags: reactjs, setstate

very new to React.

Even though there are a lot of questions regarding ReactJS on here, I am still unable to resolve this issue.

I want to reset a state or zero it, but for some reason, the state is not reset( however I can add more characters to it, see below)

Code for adding more characters(working)... :

```
var temp=this.state.numDisplay.toString() + id.toString();
this.setState( {numDisplay :  temp},  () => this.forceUpdate());
```

Code that is not causing the value to change:

```
this.setState({numDisplay : 0},  () => this.forceUpdate());
```

I have tried multiple ways of changing the numDisplay, such as using a variable that has a value of zero but those ways didnt work.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

```
class Calc extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numDisplay: 0,
      num1: 0,
      num2: 0,
      oper: ""
    };
    this.appendNum = this.appendNum.bind(this);
    this.appendoper = this.appendoper.bind(this);
  }

  appendNum(event) {
    if (
      event.target.id.toString() === "." &&
      this.state.numDisplay.toString().includes(".")
    ) {
    } else {
      var temp = this.state.numDisplay.toString() + event.target.id.toString();

      {
        while (temp.charAt(0) === "0") {
          temp = temp.substr(1);
        }
      }

      this.setState(
        {
          numDisplay: temp
        },
        () => this.forceUpdate()
      );
    }
  }

  appendoper(event) {
    if (this.state.numDisplay !== 0) {
      if (
        this.state.num1 === 0
          ? this.setState({ num1: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
          : this.setState({ num2: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
      )
        this.setState({ numDisplay: 0 }, () => this.forceUpdate());
    }
  }

  render() {
    let buttons = [];
    let cbuttons = [];

    for (var i = 9; i > -1; i--) {
      buttons.push(
        <button className="mainBtns" id={i} onClick={e => this.appendNum(e)}>
          {i}{" "}
        </button>
      );
    }

    buttons.push(
      <button id="." className="mainBtns" onClick={e => this.appendNum(e)}>
        .{" "}
      </button>
    );
    buttons.push(
      <button className="mainBtns" onClick={e => this.appendNum(e)}>
        ={" "}
      </button>
    );

    cbuttons.push(
      <button
        className="mainBtns , cBtns"
        id={"+"}
        onClick={e => this.appendoper(e)}
      >
        +
      </button>
    );
    cbuttons.push(
      <button
        className="mainBtns , cBtns"
        id={"-"}
        onClick={e => this.appendoper(e)}
      >
        -
      </button>
    );
    cbuttons.push(
      <button
        className="mainBtns , cBtns"
        id={"/"}
        onClick={e => this.appendoper(e)}
      >
        /
      </button>
    );
    cbuttons.push(
      <button
        className="mainBtns , cBtns"
        id={"*"}
        onClick={e => this.appendoper(e)}
      >
        *
      </button>
    );

    return (
      <section>
        <div id="dispArea">{this.state.numDisplay}</div>

        <div id="mainNumBtns">{buttons}</div>
        <div id="calcBtns">{cbuttons}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Calc />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Working towards a calculator, no functionality yet :(

Comment: strange. Post the full component.

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not related with react state update. You should check your if statement in appendoper method.

```
appendoper(event) {
    if (this.state.numDisplay !== 0) {
      if (
        this.state.num1 === 0
          ? this.setState({ num1: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
          : this.setState({ num2: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
      )
        this.setState({ numDisplay: 0 }, () => this.forceUpdate());
    }
  }
```

It's not reaching this statement:

```
this.setState({ numDisplay: 0 }, () => this.forceUpdate());
```

Fix the following if condition to return true or false:

```
if (
        this.state.num1 === 0
          ? this.setState({ num1: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
          : this.setState({ num2: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
      )
```

If you update as the following, your code will be running:

```
appendoper(event) {
    if (this.state.numDisplay !== 0) {
        this.state.num1 === 0
          ? this.setState({ num1: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
          : this.setState({ num2: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
        this.setState({ numDisplay: 0 }, () => this.forceUpdate());
    }
  }
```

Check also here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r1wjp90wlq

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer, the num1 and num2 are assigned values just fine, i then want the display to reset to 0 which doesnt happen

Comment: Your if statement is not correct. The result of the following expression is not true or false. So, your code is failing at this point.
this.state.num1 === 0
          ? this.setState({ num1: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )
          : this.setState({ num2: this.state.numDisplay }, () =>
              this.forceUpdate()
            )